# How to import Tailwind plugin in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

I'm trying to use npm package 'tailwindcss-flip' in my Rails 7 app.
The package docs have the following instructions:

**Install tailwindcss-flip package:**

> Install using NPM

`npm install tailwindcss-flip --save-dev`

**Install using Yarn**

> yarn add tailwindcss-flip --dev

Add plugin to your tailwind.conf.js file:
`plugins: [require("tailwindcss-flip")]`

My question is, I did pin the package in importmap, but I got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss-flip'
```

Any idea how this can work in Rails 7 (No Webpacker).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you're using `tailwindcss-rails` gem. That is the default even if you run `rails new app --css tailwind`. It uses standalone tailwind executable https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli which comes bundled with first party plugins. So any plugin in `@tailswindcss/*` should work out of the box.

To use any other tailwind plugins you must run a full node.js version of tailwind. The Rails 7 way is to use `cssbundling-rails`.

```rb
# Gemfile
# remove gem "tailwindcss-rails"
gem "cssbundling-rails"
```

```
bin/bundle install
bin/rails css:install:tailwind
```

Add build script to package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify"
}
```

Add any plugin you like after that. In your case:

```
yarn add tailwindcss-flip --dev
```

Add plugins to tailwind config. By default it is `tailwind.config.js` (standalone `tailwindcss-rails` version uses `config/tailwind.config.js` which you don't need anymore)

```
plugins: [
  require("tailwindcss-flip"),
]
```

In your layout you should only have `application` stylesheet. Remove `stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind"`

```rb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

To start compiling your css, run the build script from `package.json`

```
yarn build:css --watch
```

This should output `app/assets/builds/application.css` file. It is served by rails asset pipeline (sprockets). In case you get sprocket errors, restart everything, clear cache, check `app/assets/config/manifest.js` to include `//= link_tree ../builds`.

---

You should also have `bin/dev` script and `Procfile.dev`. Run:

```bash
bin/dev
```

to start rails server and tailwind.

Comment: If you originally had the "tailwindcss-rails" gem installed, make sure to remove Tailwind from Procfile.dev as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working setup with a Tailwind plugin (tw-elements), Rails 7, importmaps -- notably using **NO nodejs, package.json, esbuild/webpack, etc**.

After running:

```
bin/importmap pin --download tw-elements
bin/importmap pin --download tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs
```

I have in my `config/importmap.rb`:

```rb
pin "tw-elements", to: "tw-elements.js", preload: true # @1.1.0
pin "tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs", to: "tw-elements--dist--plugin.cjs.js" # @1.1.0
```

I reference these from `config/tailwind.config.js` thus:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './vendor/javascript/tw-elements.js',  // TW-ELEMENTS //
  ],
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
    require('../vendor/javascript/tw-elements--dist--plugin.cjs.js'), // TW-ELEMENTS //
  ],
}
```

Note the `../` is required in one place, but forbidden in the other!  That's because when we call `require` in the `plugins` section our working dir is `RAILS_ROOT/config`, but in `content` the paths are relative to `RAILS_ROOT`.

Behavior may vary slightly for different plugins, but this should provide a solid foundation.

Answer (score -1):

There's another option if you want to use importmap.

1 - pin required libs

```
$ ./bin/importmap pin tailwindcss-flip
```

2 - add following code to your layout file in head section

```
    <script>
      tailwind.config = {
        plugins: [
          require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
          require("tailwindcss-flip"),
        ],        
      }      
    </script>
```

3 - just use `dir=rtl` in your views

4 - PROFIT!!! :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it fails in the browser console with `Uncaught ReferenceError: tailwind is not defined`