# Tailwind and Rails – Warnings despite configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I am trying out Tailwind for the first time in a Rails app (7.0.8). I have installed the `tailwindcss-rail` gem and run `tailwindcss:install`. Steps 3 and 4 from the [rails tailwind setup guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails) are irrelevant as the code has been auto-generated already in both locations as shown:

```
content: [
  './public/*.html',
  './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
  './app/javascript/**/*.js',
  './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
],
```

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I am running the server with `./bin/dev`.

I've also added daisyui (the reason I am trying tailwind) to the configuration in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
    require('daisyui'),
  ]
```

Finally, I am running `./bin/dev` to serve the app. Despite the configuration above, my test tailwind code in my templates is not styling as expected, and I see the following in the console when I run the `dev` binary:

> 22:19:09 css.1  | warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
>
> 22:19:09 css.1  | warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

It feels like this warning may be related to the styles not showing in the browser, but I cannot figure out why I am seeing them when the configuration matches what is described in the setup document.

---

While my main question is about the warnings being shown, here is the grand total of the test Tailwind styling I have to verify function (slim template):

```
p.text-sky-400
```

Inspecting this element in the browser shows that it is getting some base Tailwind classes applied, but no color, nor any rules from the `text-sky-400` class:

[image: Screenshot of element inspector in browser listing several broad CSS rules matched.]

Comment: i just created a demo project following the rails tailwind setup guide. And it's working. Could you share how you are using tailwind in your template?

Comment: @miraj My question is more specifically about the warnings shown, however I have added an example of the very limited Tailwind styles I have added to test that are not being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I have found the issue: The `tailwindcss-rails` gem doesn't support third-party plugins like `daisyui`. The line `require('daisyui`),` in the config listed in the questin is what causes the warning. Removing that fixes the issue.

Too use third-party plugins, a different setup of tailwind is needed, as outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641967/817496).