# Javascript not working when using Tailwind Elements with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7, tailwind-elements

I just started a new rails 7 project with TailwindCSS using the new `rails new my-app --css tailwind` syntax. Tailwind CSS is working properly. I wanted to add a navbar from tailwind elements, and I followed the steps from https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/. The css in the navbar works, but the opening and closing of submenus (which I presume is all run by javascript) does not.

When digging into the details, I am seeing these lines in the `rails s` logs

```
Started GET "/TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-02-02 09:13:48 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js"):
```

I did the `npm install tw-elements` install and the `tailwind.config.cs` edits, what am I missing? Is there some conflict that with Ruby on Rails that I am not aware of? Do I really need to create a route, or is that a sign that something is not installed correctly?

Here is the `application.html.erb` where I am inserting my `<script>` line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind" , "inter-font" , "data-turbo-track" : "reload" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" , "data-turbo-track" : "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <!--here is the line I added -->
    <script src="./TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <main class="container mx-auto mt-28 px-5 flex">
        <%= yield %>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I did try the alternate step 4 by putting `import 'tw-elements';` in `app/javascript/controllers.index.js` but nothing is working.

Comment: If you continue scrolling down that quickstart guide you'll see that it uses a hosting platform called MDB GO which presumably replaces `./TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/` with an actual path. You need to find actual instruction for integrating Rails and Tailwind.

Comment: For example https://www.simplethread.com/how-to-create-a-new-rails-7-app-with-tailwind/

Comment: just to be clear: tailwindCSS is working, tailwind-ELEMENTS is not. I have searched everywhere and I cannot find anyone who has used tailwind-elements and rails together before. But it should not be that hard, it is just html, css and javascript.

Comment: As for MDB GO, that is an alternate install method. I just noticed that there is a CDN method and adding the scripts it mentioned has my project working. But I don't think that is a good long-term solution.

Comment: The reason the request is hitting the router is that the path is not in the public directory - nor is it something handed by the assets pipeline. Rails 7 doesn't really ship with a one-size fits all solution for assets handling and its up to you if you want to use import maps, webpacker or any of the other options.

Comment: [Does that help?](https://medium.com/@mauddev/cheatsheet-how-to-use-tailwind-elements-in-rails-links-f96f1a8803d1)

Answer (score 0):

==== EDIT ====

Came back to update - there's actually a page for [installing tailwind on Rails](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails), and it just works :)

==== EDIT END ====

Just had the same issue and posting the solution here.

After you have completed the steps in the tailwind elements setup, instead of the last step (the script tag):

1. Add these to your `assets.rb` initializer

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( tailwind.css tw-elements.umd.min.js )
```

2. Add this line in `application.rb`

```
//= require tw-elements.umd.min
```

3. Add the script tag in your `application.html.erb` - note the type `module` at the end:

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'tw-elements.umd.min', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', type: "module" %>
```

The solution was based on [this post](https://medium.com/@elicloudh/rails-importing-javascript-packages-from-node-modules-with-assets-pipeline-without-webpacker-98d985b22cea).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tamar do you have any example projects

Comment: @sandeeprajbhandari thanks for asking cause I forgot about this answer - turns out there is a separate install page for ROR, just updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working setup with Tailwind Elements, Rails 7, importmaps -- notably NO nodejs, package.json, esbuild/webpack, etc.

After running:

```
bin/importmap pin --download tw-elements
bin/importmap pin --download tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs
```

I have in my `config/importmap.rb`:

```rb
pin "tw-elements", to: "tw-elements.js", preload: true # @1.1.0
pin "tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs", to: "tw-elements--dist--plugin.cjs.js" # @1.1.0
```

I reference these from `config/tailwind.config.js` thus:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './vendor/javascript/tw-elements.js',  // TW-ELEMENTS //
  ],
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
    require('../vendor/javascript/tw-elements--dist--plugin.cjs.js'), // TW-ELEMENTS //
  ],
}
```

Note the `../` is required in one place, but forbidden in the other!  That's because when we call `require` in the `plugins` section our working dir is `RAILS_ROOT/config`, but in `content` the paths are relative to `RAILS_ROOT`.